# How to automatically convert the mysql's SET to its integer when SELECTing using Doctrine2?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

The [mysql's SET data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) is commonly used for representing options whereby they can be combined using bitwise operations.

eg.

```
    SELECT set_column, set_column + 0 FROM table
```

- The first would return a comma-separated list of options (eg. 'option1, option2')
- The second would return 3 (1+2)

I'm using Doctrine2 and I'm only working with objects (not using partial objects or arrays). So my question is how can I retrieve the second format when querying the entity's repository?

If I map the column to be string it returns the first format. If mapped to integer php will convert to 0 (intval('options, ...')).

A dirty hack would be adding this to the mapped attribute:

```
    @ORM\Column(name="set_column+0", type="integer")
```

... however it will cause problems when INSERTING or UPDATING.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom type for Doctrine, as it doesn't provide built-in support for `SET` type. Luckly, it's quite simple:

1. Define the type class:

   ```
   use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
   use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

   class MyCustomSetType extends Type
   {
       const TYPE = 'my_custom_set';

       private $possibleValues = array('option1', 'opton2', ..., 'optionN');

       public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
       {
           return sprintf("SET('%s')", implode(',', $this->possibleValues));
       }

       public function convertToPHPValue($values, AbstractPlatform $platform)
       {
           return explode(',', $values);
       }

       public function convertToDatabaseValue($values, AbstractPlatform $platform)
       {
           if (!is_array($values)) {
               throw new \InvalidArgumentException('...');
           }

           foreach ($values as $value) {
               if (!in_array($value, $this->possibleValues, true)) {
                   throw new \InvalidArgumentException('...');
               }
           }


           return implode(',', $values);
       }

       public function getName()
       {
           return self::TYPE;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register your newly created type:

   ```
   \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType('my_custom_set', '\My\Type\MyCustomSet');
   ```
3. Define a appropriate mapping for your entity:

   ```
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="my_custom_set")
    */
   protected $options = array();
   ```

If you want to find more about custom types read the documentation: [Custom Mapping Types](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html)

Comment: I was aware of custom types, but I don't see how this would automatically convert the SET value into its integer value, when doing a SELECT. Your example has a comma-separated list which is converted to an array. It is useful though, thanks.

Comment: Have just seen the Type class has a method that might do the job `public function convertToPHPValueSQL($sqlExpr, $platform)`